# HTTP 403.0 coming from IIS - Subcode useless and not explaining "Access denied"

Tags: iis, sitefinity

We're suddenly getting 403 "Access Denied" errors, but there's no apparent reason. 
The problem only occurs with pages where hyphens are used. For example:
http://example.com/my-page
However if we rename this page to: 
http://example.com/my_page
It works.

It's a Sitefinity CMS application/site, so we initially thought the problem was there, but we're able to get the exact same app/db up and running on testing VM and the problem disappears.

The environment is Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.

We suspect that there has been a change in the environment, but we're not sure what it could be.

One last point is that it doesn't happen with all hyphenated pages. But, all the problem pages are hyphenated pages.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on those pages - do they allow anonymous View access?
What version of .NET have you built the app against - 4.0 or 4.5.x?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev The pages are served up by a CMS system called Sitefinity so they don't physically exist on the drive. The target framework is 4.0

Comment: @Jackques, yes, I am aware of the fact, but pages do have Permissions in the Sitefinity CMS - under Actions you will find the Permissions link. What version of Sitefinity?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev sorry about that. The permissions are set to allow anonymous yes. The pages throw this error then when you change the hyphen separator to underscore it works, so I don't think it's the page permissions per se. Having tested the app in two different environments where in one it works and the other not, Telerik are suggesting that it's obviously an environment issue and that I should compare the two, but the main settings are identical so I'm having dig much deeper. Not sure where to go

Comment: Just to put Sitefinity out of the equation, what happens when you create a vanilla html file that has hyphen in its name, e.g. static-file.html? Do you get the same 403? If so, then it is definitely something in IIS/firewall. 
Can you enable IIS logging and see the sub-status code associated with the 403?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I can certainly try the static file approach, sounds good to me. On the second point, the logging is on but it always gives a sub-status code of 0.